# SDLWEB8: tridionThumbnailCache folder permission

Tags: web8, web8.5

I moved tridionThumbnailCache folder and multimedia image into D drive and updated `<Tridion.ThumbnailDirectory>D:\Tridion\tridionThumbnailCache</Tridion.ThumbnailDirectory>` in **System.config**.

Now I am facing issue multimedia component image not displaying in CME due to folder permission issue.

Looking solutions for tridionThumbnailCache permission updates.

Comment: Have you set that the same user have same permissions over new folder just as over old one?

Comment: I moved old folder into another d drive.

Comment: If you move a Folder with inherited permissions, you can effectively change its ACL. Try using ProcMon to see why the file access fails.

Comment: @RickPannekoek yes i agree, also my point. Folder can change its inheritance if moved. Also, you should check which user should have write permissions over tridionThumbnailCache folder. I guess that  it should be MTSUser.

Comment: I guess it should be NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

Comment: @ Rick Pannekoek: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDLWeb not support to custimize the Thumbnail cache directory due to permission issue. I revert my custimized change and using default directory and permissions.

```
    <!-- Thumbnail cache directory -->
    <Tridion.ThumbnailDirectory>/ThumbnailCache</Tridion.ThumbnailDirectory>
```

Answer (score 3):

actually, they do. I worked this out with SDL support recently. you keep the thumbnail cache setting there. But that's a virtual path under IIS. What you do in IIS is set new virtual directory to your custom location.

You can do that in PowerShell like this:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site "SDL Web" -Name "ThumbnailCache" –Application "WebUI" -PhysicalPath "D:\Tridion\tridionThumbnailCache"
```